# How can I retrieve HTML data from a website realtime?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm working on a small program to notify me whenever a road test appointment pops up that is prior to November 2021. I just started learning Python and I have past experience in java in a coding class in high school

The problem is when I use

```
html_text = requests.get("https://www12.honolulu.gov/csdarts/frmApptInt.aspx").text
print(html_text)
```

it prints out data that belongs to a different page of the website *(for example I want it to display the `koolau` location and NOT `any` location)* .

I figured out how to automate the process of getting to that page, and how to print out the https, but I am having trouble combining the two.

This is my first post so sorry if this is wordy or incorrect. Here is the full code-

```
from urllib.parse import urlunparse, urlparse 
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.request import ( urlopen, urlretrieve)  
import os 
import sys
import time 
import requests

html_text =
requests.get("https://www12.honolulu.gov/csdarts/frmApptInt.aspx").text
print(html_text) soup = bs(html_text, 'lxml')

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C://webdrivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www12.honolulu.gov/csdarts/frmApptInt.aspx")

click_eligible = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[3]/input") 
click_eligible.click()

click_location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/select")
click_location.click()

time.sleep(0.2) 
click_koolau =
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[@value='6']")
click_koolau.click()

find = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/p[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/input[1]")
find.click()
```

Comment: If you post code please use the right formatting option (`{}` button).

Comment: right, when I press that button it only allows me to paste 1 line in, do i have to paste each line in individually? @KlausD.

UPDATE - @ pmadhu helped me by suggesting an edit to format the code. I still dont understand how you fit all of that in xD sorry

Comment: You paste in your code, you mark it, you press the button.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you @KlausD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to get the html for the source:

```
html = driver.page_source
```